# Авторизация и закрытый доступ к страницам с Angular2, Spring Boot и Nginx

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, spring

Никак не пойму как делается `ajax` авторизация в `spring security`. У меня есть фронт на `Angular2` + `nginx`. Бэк на `Spring Boot`. Как мне в теории организовать авторизацию и закрытый доступ к некоторым страницам фронта ? В документации по `Spring Security` не могу найти ничего подобного.

Comment: Писать свой аутентификатор с приемом респонса (login/password) и обработкой уже непосредственно из Security

Comment: @GenCloud, то есть, я передаю cookie (после логина/пароля) на бэк и он отвечает, доступна страница или нет. Так ?

Comment: Post запрос с отсылкой данных json или формой(как вы будете считывать не знаю) и непосредственно контроллер с функцией аутентификации